# Computation of a double exponential integral

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I want to understand the behavior of this integral 
$$ \int_0^x e^{-\frac{c}{t^2}} \frac{1}{t^5} e^{-\frac{c_2}{(x-t)^2}} \frac{1}{(x-t)^5} dt. $$
The ideal answer would be a way to explicitly compute this, but I have no clue. This integral is clearly definite, but my problem is to understand quantitatively its behavior for small and large values of $c$ and $c_2$. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: At first i would simplify the integrand!

Comment: What would be the best way to do so? The two obvious changes of variable ($t \to \frac{1}{t}$ or $t \to \frac{1}{x-t}$) seem to lead to something more complicated.

Comment: Why did you delete the second part of the question ?

Comment: I think the integral I had was not convergent, near 0 it is homogeneous to $1/t^k$ for $k \geq 2$... I need to check again the entire series computation

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Assuming $t<x$, $x>0$,$$\int\frac{1}{t^k} \frac{1}{(x-t)^l}\,dt=x^{-k-l+1} B_{\frac{t}{x}}(1-k,1-l)$$

Answer (score 0):

I mean this here $$e^{-\frac{c}{t^2}-\frac{c_2}{(x-t)^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{(t(x-t))^5}$$